# I want to change my navbar from login to logout when the user is already login ESJ NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

My problem here is when the user is already logged in, I want to change my navbar to logout. I am using Nodejs and Ejs templates for my web project. My code is below. please help me to figure this out. I am also using Level 1 Authentication. I am trying to do basic first before I do the hashing. Thank you very much!

APP.JS

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const res = require("express/lib/response");

const app = express();


app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));



//TODO
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/barangayportalDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const userSchema = {
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    conpassword: String,
    role: String
};
const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("main");
});

app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
    res.render("login");
});


app.get("/register", function (req, res) {
    res.render("register");
});

app.get("/logout", async (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/")

});


app.post("/login", function (req, res) {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const role = "admin";

    User.findOne({ email: username }, function (err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundUser) {
                if (foundUser.role === role) {
                    res.render("adminportal")
                }

                else if (foundUser.password === password) {
                    res.render("portal")
                }

            }
        }
    })
});


app.post("/register", function (req, res) {

    const newUser = new User({
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        email: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        conpassword: req.body.conpassword

    });
    newUser.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("portal")
        }
    });

});



//---------------------------------------

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Here is my Navbar.ejs This is where I want to change my login to signout.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Barangay Portal</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#News">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-expanded="false">
              Request
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/reqbrgyid">Dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Drop Down</a></li>
         
           
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Other</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item navbar-distance">
              //this i want to change this to Sign out and remove the register button as well
            <a class="nav-link " href="/login">Sign in</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item navbar-distance">
            <a class="nav-link nav-border-without" href="#contacts">Talk to Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item navbar-distance">
            <a class="nav-link nav-border-with" href="/register">Register</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

While rendering the page you can pass the auth status which is Boolean value and according to that you can toggle the login button

Comment: I think tried that already, but maybe my way is different from what you are suggesting

Comment: Can you share the code , in which you have passed auth status and also can you tell some more details of work flow like does your main page contains navbar

Comment: my app.js and navbar.ejs codes are already posted above. my main page has a navbar, if I signed in, I want the main page navbar changed to signout and remove the sign-in button.

login form > login = true > navbar (display: sign out)
loginform > login = false > navbar (display: sign in)

Comment: in res.render function along with rendering page , send an object with auth status and in ejs template  when you're calling api , access this auth status and manipulate that sign in button according to auth status  using javascript i.e manipulate dom according to condition

Comment: what do you mean is something like this right? res.render("/portal", {login: true}); am i right? How can I pass it to my ejs? I tried to do if-else and use this <% %> but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yes , the same way , access that login in ejs file , when you call api and you can access that login button dom element and you can manipulate through javascript or if you are doing the other way as you said then check for right syntax of ejs for conditional rendering